# Async communication of swift and Javascriptcore

Tags: swift, wkwebview, javascriptcore

I want to use the Async functionality offered by WKWebView outside web view. 
The JS Context option does not provide the Async functionality.

In WKWebView, I write my logic as follows.

```
func swiftFunc1() {
   webView.evaluateJavaScript("jsFunc1(), completionHandler: nil)
}
```

In javascript code I post a message to swift

```
function jsFunc1() {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.myMsg.postMessage("call swiftFunc2");
}
```

The swift code can then call appropriate JS callback as a part of handling message.

But this is dependent upon the webview being the foreground view. If I want to use the JS logic independent of the webview, JSContext is the option. I tried following

```
func swiftFunc1() {
    myCtxt = JSContext()
    exportedToJS = exportToJS() //confirms to JSExport and uses @objc
    myCtxt.setObject(exportedToJS.self, forKeyedSubscript: "swiftIface")
    myFunc = myCtxt.objectForKeyedSubscript("jsFunc1")
    myFunc.callWithArguments(nil)
}
```

Now in javascript code I cannot post a message to swift. If I try to call a swift function as follows, code gets stuck forever.

```
function jsFunc1() {
   swiftIface.swiftFunc2() // This creates a deadklock
 }
```

How can I achieve either of the following without "returning" from the called Javascript function jsFunc1()?

1. Either post a message to swift so that it can take appropriate action
2. Or call a swift function so that the appropriate action is taken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do I understand you right, if you do not want your javscript to terminate after execution?

If I understood you wrong, maybe following helps (I am not at home at Mac to test, but maybe it works if you modify your code as follows).

**Option 1: Blocks**

The swiftFunc1 could look like this:

```
func swiftFunc1() {
    myCtxt = JSContext()
    myCtxt.setObject(unsafeBitCast(swiftFunc2, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "swiftFunc2")
    exportedToJS = exportToJS() //confirms to JSExport and uses @objc
    myCtxt.evaluateScript("swiftFunc2()")
}
```

Your swiftFunc2 would look like this:

```
let swiftFunc2: @convention(block) Void -> Void = { 
  // do something here
}
```

Your JS code would look like this:

```
function jsFunc1() {
   swiftFunc2();
 }
```

**Option 2: JSExport**
Your have an exported class which is accessible for all javascript:

```
import Foundation
import JavaScriptCore
@objc class JavascriptHandler: NSObject, JavascriptHandlerExport {
  let context: JSContext = JSContext()

  init () {
    context.setObject(self, forKeyedSubscript: "MyJSHandler") // set the object name for self accessible in javascript code
  }
  func swiftFunc1() {
    context.evaluateScript("MyJSHandler.swiftFunc2();")
  }
  func swiftFunc2 () {
    // do something here
  }
}
```

Your protocol for the exported class.Here you have to declare all properties and methods you want to use with Javascript.

```
import Foundation
import JavaScriptCore
@objc protocol JavascriptHandlerExport: JSExport {
  func swiftFunc2 ( ) -> Void
}
```

With this it should be possible for you to call a function from javascript and still let it continue.
You can now access the functions of the class JavascriptHandler from Javascript like this in this example:

```
MyJSHandler.swiftFunc2();
```

---

If you want to seperate the class where your WebView is from the one where your JS logic lies that should also not be a problem. You should also be able to combine the block syntax with the JSExport method.

Let me know if it's not working/behaving as wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But does this mean that I should only be using blocks/closures to get around this? JSExport can not handle this kind of call sequence, is it?

Comment: It should be possible too with JSExport. Maybe if I have time tomorrow I can try to give an example.

Comment: Looking forward to it!

Comment: Could you find this possible?

Comment: I have tried this kind of arrangement previously and found that XCode simply hangs when there is a cycle like this.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908059/call-to-swift-method-from-javascript-hangs-xcode-and-application

Comment: Sorry, i might be able in future to do tests on this but unfortunately not now...